# Can 2008 engine be installed in 2009 liberty?

Tags: engine, jeep, liberty

my engine gave out and dealer replaced it. Is it possible for 2008 engine to be put in a 2009 Liberty?

I did my oil change now, and the oil filter for 2009 Jeep Liberty did not fit. The filter was Mopar 4781452BB which are used for 2008 Liberty (I think fits 2002-08 models). The reason I'm asking is I have a kick/knock when driving around 50mph in a slight incline or having slight acceleration at that speed. When I checked with my local mechanic, he said this might be due to ignition coil/cable problem (seems it hasn't been replaced along with the engine) or fuel related.  He asked me to use a cleaner and it didnt rectify it.

I checked in Mopar site and the ignition coil for 2008 & 2009 are different. Before I go the dealer, I want to be sure. The dealer rep wont even get up unless I consent to a $140 diagnostic charge for anything/everything. For ex, when I first went to the dealer abt the kick/knock, his response was "there is no way an engine can make noise, it has to be your transmission. It will be a $140 to check and leave the vehicle we will check in 3 days". Thats I went to the mechanic

Comment: The engine used in your Liberty is a [PowerTech V6 3.7L](https://www.allpar.com/mopar/37.html). It was made from 2001-2009. It is basically a 4.7L V8 with two less cylinders. It looks as though it is interchangeable, however, I don't know that for sure. It is not uncommon for a change in oil filters between years, but would surely be an indicator you got a previous year engine. When the dealer said a "brand new engine", they probably meant a "brand new rebuilt engine". Both essentially mean the same thing and cost would be the same. Mopar no longer makes your engine, so rebuilt seems likely.

Comment: I seem to remember a tsb about flash updating this models pcm (engine & transmission control module) for hard shifting. You may want to consider looking into if your pcm's programming has been updated to the most recent calibrations. If not it might do you some good to flash update it, clear out old setting and reconfigure them. If this was not done when new engine was put in, it could be part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Where did the replacement engine come from?

Look up a VIN decoder for the Jeep online. That'll tell you which engine it came with. Then check the engine serial number (it's on the block). More google-fu will tell you if it's the same model of engine that the car came with. If not, you then need to use Google again to match the ECU to the Engine.

If you supplied the engine, tough. If the dealer supplied the engine, talk direct to Jeep. They may be able to apply some pressure on the dealer. I have to be honest - I'd pay the money, rather than rely on a mechanic who doesn't know what the issue is or how to diagnose it. All he gave you was hope, not an answer.

One thing to be aware of; the mechanics in a lot of dealerships are paid based on the billable work they've produced. If you get a free diagnostic, you're saving $140 - but the mechanic isn't getting paid at all, and some diagnostic work can take hours.

Comment: I was told it is a new engine and had the dealer put it in. I will check the VIN number tomorrow & update. The mechanic is an exp & well respected guy. When I had trouble, I went first to him. He heard the sound & in 2 secs told me I need new engine, asked me to go to dealer. Dealer said I need transmission & will cost $2K so was happy. 2 days later told I need engine. Same thing for the kicking sound. I could feel it coming from engine, and mechanic exactly told me all the symptoms I would be experiencing, while dealer told no way its the engine. I have less trust on dealer than the mechanic